# inserting data in mysql previously defined variables

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am using this code to get data from Json and insert them to mysql. However it inserts no records in the data base.

```
    <?php  
    include("db.php");  
    $currsiteurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/1597233119';  
     $graph = json_decode(file_get_contents($currsiteurl));  
     $id = $graph->id;  
     echo "id        : ".$id;   
     echo "<br>";
     $username = $graph->username;  
      echo "username : ".$username;  
      echo "<br>";
     $gender = $graph->gender;  
      echo "gender   : ".$gender;  
      echo "<br>";
       $locale = $graph->locale;  
         echo "locale   : ".$locale;  


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_data (id, username, gender, locale) 
         VALUES ('.$id', '.$username', '.$gender', '.$locale')");    
          ?>
```

Can any one show me whereis the mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_data (id, username, gender, locale) 
     VALUES ('.$id', '.$username', '.$gender', '.$locale')");
```

You are creating a single string (with embedded variables) so the dots '.' are not required.

If either of the id or gender are number-fields then this is likely to be what prevents the data from being inserted (with the dots). (If they are numbers they don't require surrounding apostrophes either.)

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated, use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: even when I delete the dots it inserts nothing

Comment: Are the variables echo-ing the values you expect? Create a string variable for the sql-statement and echo it (or `print_r()`) and try and run it from within phpMyAdmin (or similar).

Comment: Actually the id is a number but the gender is a text and the eching is ok

Comment: You should also be checking whether the connection was made, and the return result from `mysql_query`, etc..

Comment: try to do an answer from phpmyadmin an past query result of your answer here ! i dont see any error in your query except the point,as @AndyG said , may be it's something in your db.php

Comment: Thanks for all AndyG and @FaceOfJock

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Andy G states:

1. You should use prepared statements to make sure the data you are receiving is properly escaped to avoid sql injection attacks: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
2. To assist debugging queries, add `echo mysql_error()` after your mysql_query statement to print the error (or use one of the new fangled methods mentioned in the alert here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: Good point and prectice but I'm not sure facebook graph will be running SQL injection attacks that often!